# How to graph seaborn countplot without dataframe?

Tags: python, math, graph, seaborn

I want to make a seaborn `countplot()`. I don't have a dataframe, but I know what I want to graph.

I want to graph something like this[image]

Where I can change the count/class/data values.

I know I need a dataframe but I don't have any data.

I really just need a way to manually graph this.

I have tried something like this, but I don't have a dataframe so it doesn't work:

```
data= sns.load_dataset("data")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", data=data)
```

How could I make it so I can manually graph the data? Let's say I want to go from 0 to 3000 like in the picture, and have 5 Heartbeat classes on the bottom.

Is there any way I can manually do this? Maybe make a list with data and input it?-

Comment: Can you please explain what you have already tried? I have a similar question.

Comment: @HeatherMcall If you want to pay someone to do your job then don't use SO for it. Please read [ask] and pass the [tour]. On the other hand, the questions in SO are not subject to any deadline.

Comment: @boetis If you have a similar problem and want to get an answer then you must create your own post. Post editions must be cosmetic (typos, format code, etc), beyond that the edition is reverted.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean? I just improved a question that was similar to one that I had.

Comment: Hey why is my question closed I wanted help on it

Comment: @boetis The edits that users other than the OP can make should not be on the background, they are only for correction of typographical errors, formatting code (do not add, modify or delete code). Please use `@username`

Comment: @HeatherMcall 1. Read the banner at the top of your post so that you understand the cause of the closure. 2. Stop offering money to do your homework, so it is not the dynamics of the site so read the links that I indicate in the other comment so that you know the philosophy and dynamics of the site.

Comment: Wait i added details can it please be opened again I really need help on this topic

Comment: @HeatherMcall I see that you have copied the same edition as `@boetis`, are you the same user?. Stop offering money as I will report the action to a moderator and he will see what sanction to give.

Comment: @HeatherMcall Note: If you notice a similar comment has already been removed because offering money should not be an incentive to get responses. If you want someone to do your homework for money then find another forum, SO is not for that.

Comment: What is SO? Also idk who @boetis is I just copied it because I want it re opened

Comment: @eyllanesc can you please re open it?

Comment: @HeatherMcall Please use  `@username`. SO: Stack Overflow. *can you please re open it?*: No